# php.ini settings change not taking effect for large file uploads

Tags: apache-2.2, php, upload

My server was just reprovisioned, and my application which uploads large (100M+) files now breaks upon re-installation.

the symptom is quite consistent :  smaller files (8mb in my tests) upload just fine.  Larger files cut off at quite close to the same point every time given a particular computer.  a file that fails at 26% will fail at just about the same every time.  One that takes 1:40s to fail will take within 2 seconds of that every time, before failure.

I have set my php.ini settings extravagently :

post_max_size = 512M
upload_max_filesize = 512M
max_input_time = 3600
max_execution_time 3600

Is there possibly a setting at the Apache Level which would override PHP?

Answer (score 0):

There are two php.ini available - one for Apache and other for php cli. Please make sure you are changing the which apache uses. To find the path of php.ini that apache uses, use phpinfo() function in a file and browse it from browser and see the section 'Loaded configuration'. It will give you the path from which apache is loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I have checked phpinfo on the server, and the correct php.ini files is in use, and the values displayed in phpinfo() are correct.